# Семантика и СЕО для тега a

Tags: css3, html5, seo

Интересует насколько правдив ответ сеошника

---

Как с точки зрения семантики, так и с точки зрения СЕО — тэг  должен использоваться только для формирования ссылок, ведущих на другие страницы сайта или другой интернет-ресурс. Для управления элементами текущей страницы (показать / скрыть, изменить стиль, переместить, подгрузить и т.д.) должны использоваться элементы `<span>`, `<button>`, `<div>`, `<li>`. Именно на них вешаются обработчики событий.

---

Например, есть `tabs bootstrap 4`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Исходя из данного утверждения, код должен выглядеть так:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-link active">Active</span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-link">Link</span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-link">Link</span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-link disabled">Link</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Насколько это соответствует истине?

Comment: ну в целом так и есть, разве что  я бы ul заменил на  nav, семантики и сео ради, в конце концов этот тег для этого и создан

Comment: Если элемент интерактивный, (пользователь может с ним взаимодействовать, кликать к примеру) то это `button` или `a`, в другом случае `span, div ...` итд. Ведёт на новую страницу, ресурс тогда `a`, в остальных `button`.

Comment: @Alexander Zaytsev - получается создатели bootstrap,(например, табы) - не испол. семантику. Но они чем же то руководствовались, когда использовали тег a (которые не ведут на другие страницы сайта )

Comment: Я во все тонкости не погружался, возможно для чего-то это создавалось, ссылка на то и ссылка чтоб на что-то ссылаться ))